# Duplicate an object in a list

Tags: c#, list

How do I copy (and insert) the last object in a list.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string first {get;set;}
    public string second {get;set;}
}

List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
list.Add(new MyObject{first = "one", second = "two"});
list.Add(new MyObject{first = "here", second = "there"});
list.Add(new MyObject{first = "car", second = "plane"});

MyObject newObj = new MyObject();
list.Add(newObj);
```

It seems as if the last two objects in the list is references to the same object. How do I create a new object that is still a copy of the last object in the list?

**EDIT**
I shouldn't have simplified my problem and the class (not actually called MyObject) for this example. It's actually much larger with more children objects and lists.

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: Because if I change values in the last object they both get the change.

Comment: Then the code you are testing isn't the code you posted here.

Comment: That's right. I've flagged it for removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common ways:

(1) Write a *Copy Constructor* for the MyObject class, and use it to make a copy of the object, then insert the copy.

(2) Or write a *Clone* method for the MyObject class, and use that to make a copy, then insert the copy.

However, in the code you presented, you are NOT making a copy of anything, nor are you inserting into the list a reference to an existing object.

Here's an example how you can do it:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string first
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string second
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyObject DeepClone()
    {
        return new MyObject{ first = this.first, second = this.second;}
    }
}

// Then you can do this:

List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
list.Add(new MyObject{first = "one", second = "two"});
list.Add(new MyObject{first = "here", second = "there"});
list.Add(new MyObject{first = "car", second = "plane"});

list.Add(list[list.Count-1].DeepClone());
```

Answer (score 1):

They aren't, you have four `MyObject`s, all different.

If you are comparing objects, you should define an equals method, based on the values, if these are value objects. Otherwise define equals appropriately.

Read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

**EDIT** after the question was edited (I could have sworn it was edited!):

You should write a constructor that accepts another `MyObject` as an argument and copies the values.

As strings are immutable, it's safe to copy references to them (rather than try to duplicate the string). When you change the string value on object `a`, that will not affect object `b`.

By the way, `MyObject` is not a good name for a class!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting into the murky waters of cloning, shallow and deep copies here.
But with a simple class like that, you should be ok with:

```
var newObj = new MyObject();
newObj.first = list[3].first;
newObj.second = list[3].second;

list.Add(newObj);
```

And this is only because first and second are strings, and therefore assignment is not by reference.

Also, looking at your current code, your list would have 4 different 'MyObject' instances, with the last one having neither of the 'first' or 'second' properties initialised to anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magical way to copy an object if you haven't overridden `Clone`. But it's simple as:

```
MyObject last = list.Last();
list.Add(new MyObject{first = last.first, second = last.second});
```